# Using xpath to access HTML within matching div

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to loop through a series of p tags on a source page. Within each p tag there will be formatted text, e.g. `<p>hello, my name is <b>bob</b></p>`

I would like to each `hello, my name is <b>bob</b>` but am currently only getting `hello, my name is bob` without the `<b>` tags.

I assume nodeValue is not the correct call but unsure what to use

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$row = $xpath->query('//div[@class="article-body"]/p');

foreach($row as $r) {
  echo $r->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: nodeValue is basically "innerText" - any text nodes, WITHOUT html tags. you want innerHTML instead, hence the dupe

Comment: I appreciate the reply. Whilst echo $r->nodeValue;  works if I use echo $r->innerHTML I get nothing output ?